# c# Revert on checkbox unchecked

Tags: c#, checkbox, return, unchecked

My goal is when the checkbox is unchecked to have label1 return to it's value before the checkbox was checked.

```
 private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            if
              (checkBox1.Checked)
                label1.Text = textBox1.Text + label1.Text;

            else

                label1.Text = label1.Text; //return to previous value?
        }
    }
```

The way mentioned above, label1 'sticks' to the value when the checkbox is unchecked.

I tried using the label1.Refresh but it didn't work.

Is there a more effective way to get the result I'm looking for?

Comment: Here you loss default value of label `label1.Text = textBox1.Text + label1.Text;`. You should keep it in instance variable to restore it.

Comment: `label1.Text = label1.Text;` does nothing because the label doesnt know what it used to be - you changed it.  create a string var to hold the value to revert to

Comment: Is your project a WinForms, WPF or Web, or what else ? Giorgos Betsos , Raging Bull and Jakob Olsen provided some solutions, but all of them assume a specific environment, that you haven't specified.

Answer (score 1):

Save the value before updating it. Then revert when unchecked.

```
private string _lastValue = string.Empty;
    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            if
                (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                _lastValue = label1.Text;
                label1.Text = textBox1.Text + label1.Text;
            }

            else

                label1.Text = _lastValue;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a variable to store the previous value of the label.

```
string DefaultLabelValue="";

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DefaultLabelValue=lable1.Text;
}

private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
        label1.Text = textBox1.Text + label1.Text;
    else
        label1.Text = DefautLabelValue;
}
```

Comment: label1 won't always be the same though, so I can't just set a predefined "something"?

Comment: @EyeSeeSharp: If so, you can set it in `Form_Load` event. See the edit in my answer. If it is not what you are looking for, please explain a little bit more.

Comment: label1 is derived from an online string (which can change) acquired on a buttonclick. If I create 'string DefaultLabelValue = "";' it just adds in that value. I need to save it somehow to revert back to it when the checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: @EyeSeeSharp: Can you tell me an example?